# (HTML/CSS) iOS Safari Navigation Bar and Full-height DIV Background Issue

Tags: html, css, iphone, background-image, mobile-safari

I have a simple full width and full height background DIV with a background image (the 200% height is for a parallax script, not related to my issue). On the mobile safari browser, when scrolling down and the navigation bar disappers, for a real short time there is a visible gap at the place of the navigation bar and the DIV "falls" down instead of being full Viewport height behind. Any hints? It must be related to the image, it doesn`t appear with a background color.

```css
.wrapper {position: fixed; height:200%!important; width:100%; background: url(../img/beton.jpg); background-size:cover; top:-100%;}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper"> </div>
```

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out? It seems like only backgrounds attached to the element don't get this slow repaint issue.

Comment: Just saw my old threat here. Solved it in the meantime. For anybody finding this topic through searching: It is because of the disappearing menu bar. The picture needs to resize which takes a short moment. I think there is no real fix but you can solve that by giving the image a height more than 100% (e.g. 120vh).